# How to set a relative path in a Generic Test's(Visual Studio 2010) working directory and summary results file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, relative-path, generic-test

How to set a relative path in a Generic Test's(Visual Studio 2010) working directory and summary results file ?

As far I looked there is no way to set these locations programmatically in Generic test because the generic test has only properties page and no page to write C# code.

I have a folder structure as follows

c:\Files\GenericTestFolder\generictest.sln
c:\Files\SummaryFiles\summary.xml

Now I need to set the working directory to the following (To run an external program)
c:\Files\

And the Summary Results file location to:
c:\Files\SummaryFiles\summary.xml

I tried the following options to set the location of working directory(WD) and summary file(SF) location :

1. setting WD to "..\" or ".\" or "\" -> all of these seem to set the directory to c:\, so this is not useful for me.
2. Using a visual studio's inbuilt environment variable like %TestDeploymentDirectory% don't seem to work with "..\" , i.e %TestDeploymentDirectory% ..\ does not translate to parent of %TestDeploymentDirectory% during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%TestLocation%`. Which represents the location of the .GenericTest file.

[Source](http://intellitect.com/relative-paths-for-visual-studio-generic-tests/)